# What does SCM stand for?

Tags: version-control, terminology

In the software world, it seems that SCM is an unfortunately overloaded acronym.

It can mean:-

1. [Source Code Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)
2. [Software Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management)

Which one of these is the dominant term? Do they mean the same thing?

To me Source Code Management is essentially synonymous with Version Control. Whereas Software Configuration Management is a larger subject, which potentially includes Build and Release Management as well.

However looking on Wikipedia, it lists Subversion as a Software Configuration Management tool, which is at most only tangentially true.

Build and Software Management has [come up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300703/what-release-management-solutions-are-worth-investigating/2575851#2575851) before, but nothing definitive has been said on the matter, unfortunately.

Comment: Is this a poll? If so it should be CW. and my vote would go for #2, and I agree with your description of it.

Comment: Frustrating when an issue closes on SO and you have an answer. In lieu:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git "source control management (SCM) system"

Comment: If you look at Atlassian's definition, it means Version control, I extracted it below:

Source code management (SCM) is used to track modifications to a source code repository. SCM tracks a running history of changes to a code base and helps resolve conflicts when merging updates from multiple contributors. SCM is also synonymous with Version control. 

from https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/source-code-management#:~:text=Source%20code%20management%20(SCM)%20is,also%20synonymous%20with%20Version%20control.

Answer (score 10):

Software configuration management.  But for most of us that effectively means source code management.

Answer (score 5):

The top three results on [acronym finder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/SCM.html) are:

> `******`  SCM Supply Chain Management
>   `******`    SCM Software Configuration Management
>   `******`    SCM Source Code Management

Where the stars indicate the rank of the result.

So it looks like both are equally valid and equally used.

Answer (score 5):

Software Configuration Management.

Generally, I use/hear Source Code Management when talking about, well, source code. On the other hand, if you're keeping config files (things in /etc, application-specific config files, etc.) in an SCM, then a lot of people expand the acronym to Software Configuration Management.

So its all about what you're managing ;)