# What does SCM stand for in meaning of trac, redmine

Tags: version-control, trac, redmine, abbreviation

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575922/what-exactly-does-scm-stand-for) similar question, but it doesn't seem to be correct in meaning of trac, redmine.

Does anyone know this for sure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does SCM stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575922/what-exactly-does-scm-stand-for)

Comment: This question seems to imply that you read some source that describes Trac and Redmine as SCM tools, but you don't cite any example of that and I can't find any instance of anyone saying that except for the accepted answer right here. That leaves this question a bit unclear and confused. It seems to me that they straightforwardly are *not* SCM tools, contrary to what the Q&A here both imply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, really. *Software configuration management* encompasses *source code management*. Trac and redmine do both, really. VCS (version control system) is typically a better term because it's unambiguous.

Comment: as far as i know trac and redmine are tools to manage work and bugs, not code (at least this is what i use it for). git, mercurial or svn are VCSs

Comment: @seler both Trac and Redmine offer interfaces to VCSs like svn or git. You are correct, they are not VCSs in themselves, but they play a role in source code management (perhaps just not the way that you use them).