# What's the difference between dependency:copy mojo used in command line and configured same pulgin in pom file as build plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-scm

I want to find all dependencies of io.airlift:node:0.112, with downloading minimum files:

1. Using command **%M2_HOME%/bin/mvn dependency:copy -Dmdep.outputScope=true -DincludeScope=compile -DincludeParents=true  -DoutputFile="F:\temp\mytemp5" -DexcludeTransitive=true -f "F:\maven-plugins\node-0.112.pom"**, it is downloading **org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8.1**.
2. If I create a dummy pom and have dependency to node-0.112, and then run the same command on dummy pom, it doesn't download **org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8.1**. Below is my pom file:

   ```
   <project>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>dummy</groupId>
     <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <packaging>pom</packaging>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>io.airlift</groupId>
        <artifactId>node</artifactId>
        <version>0.112</version>
        <type>pom</type>
       </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
         <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.8</version>
             <executions>
               <execution>
                 <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                   <addParentPoms>true</addParentPoms>
                   <copyPom>true</copyPom>
                   <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                   <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                   <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                   <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                 </configuration>
               </execution>
             </executions>
           </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </build>
     </project>
   ```

Also **org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8.1** is not even returned as dependencies for both methods.

Why is maven trying to download this extra plugin? What is the best way to find dependencies without downloading extra plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`io.airlift:node:0.112`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/airlift/airlift/0.112/airlift-0.112.pom) pom has the following lines in it:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/airlift/airlift.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:airlift/airlift.git</developerConnection>
  <url>https://github.com/airlift/airlift/tree/master</url>
  <tag>0.112</tag>
</scm>
```

SCM stands for [Software Configuration Management](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575945/1768232), which is basically the part of the pom that defines how the authors maintain their source. See link for more information

[So, the executable is this; there's not much at that link but you can take a look.](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-providers-git/index.html) This causes the `org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8.1` to be downloaded to facilitate the project's connection to it's git repository.  It's not a dependency on the project itself, but it *is a dependency on how the project is maintained* - by using git for version control.

Therefore, if you execute `mvn dependency:copy`, it will download the `gitexe`, but if you create a new project that **doesn't** define the git scm (and, in fact, defines no SCM at all), then it won't download the executable.

Comment: Does defining execution in pom file like experiment #2 for finding dependencies has any disadvantage like running unwanted mojos defined in dependent poms ? I just want to find out the dependencies and thus want to run only dependency:tree mojo ?

Comment: @NalinRajGupta No, it should be independent of other mojos, but it will download transitive dependencies.